# How and where to perform response composition in microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices

We want to show alternate of a product like most of the e-commerce websites does. In our case, we need to fetch data from multiple microservices.

- **Products** - Stores all product information
- **Prices** - In our case prices are complex and subject to user's location and other parameters. Hence we made it a separate microservice.
- **Reviews** - It manages ratings and reviews about a product.

The end product will be `List<AlternateProduct>` which would have an image, description, rating out of 5 and a number of reviews.

In microservice architecture, what is the right place to compose a response from multiple microservices?

**Approatch 1**:

- MVC/Rest API approaches APIGateway
- API Gateway make an async call to all microservices
- The response will be returned to MVC/WebAPI. Where the composition of response can be performed.

**Approatch 2**:

- MVC/Rest API approaches APIGateway
- API Gateway make an async call to Products microservice.
- Products microservice will call other microservice and perform composition and returns `List<UlternateProduct>`

Please help me decide!

Comment: Don't you think my answer is good enough? :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would go for **Approach 1** sine you can download the list of Products you need and than run 2 other request in parallel for downloading  Prices and Reviews.

After your receive response from all 3 requests than you build the model and return it.

I think that Gateway API should be smart enough to make calls to different services and build the result that need to return.